# Wireguard taking ~5mins to successfully perform handshake

Tags: wireguard

I successfully set up a Wireguard VPN using PiVPN a bit more than a month ago and have been using it successfully ever since. A couple of days ago it started acting up and when I click **Activate** it takes ~5mins to successfully perform the handshake, the logs only read:

```
2022-02-03 15:01:48.708001: [TUN] [Depa] Handshake for peer 1 (==IP==) did not complete after 5 seconds, retrying (try 2)
```

And then it succeeds. Any ideas how to debug this?

[image: Wireguard logs pt 1]

[image: Wireguard logs pt 2]